# Recovery Reboot with Commands

Tags: java, android, process, recovery, reboot

I don't understand why Android does not reboot automatically when the following code is running. In order to fix this, I added System.exit(0); and it works, but why not without this?
I don't think that System.exit(0); is the best way to fix it.
Thanks in advance!

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
os.write("mkdir -p /cache/recovery/\n".getBytes());
os.write("echo 'boot-recovery' >/cache/recovery/command\n".getBytes());

os.write("echo '--wipe_cache' >> /cache/recovery/command\n".getBytes());

// Trigger the reboot
os.write("echo 'reboot' >> /cache/recovery/command\n".getBytes());
os.write("reboot recovery".getBytes());
os.flush();

// If I add System.exit(0); it works, but why not without this?
```

Comment: Does adding a '\n' to "reboot recovery" help?